# How to join six tables and fetch data from six table in sql?

Tags: sql-server, join

hi i have 6 tables from that i want access data.and display it in one table.the tables are

**t1**

```
name|date     |item       |remarks|size
abc |18-2-2015|25mm series|done   |25
xyz |17-2-2015|25mm series|done   |30
```

**t2**

```
name|date     |item       |remarks|size
abc |14-2-2015|30mm series|done   |25
xyz |16-2-2015|30mm series|done   |30
```

**t3**

```
name|date     |item       |remarks|size
abc |11-2-2015|35mm series|done   |25
xyz |13-2-2015|35mm series|done   |30
```

**t4**

```
name|date     |item       |remarks|size
abc |10-2-2015|40mm series|done   |25
abc |15-2-2015|40mm series|done   |30
xyz |16-2-2015|40mm series|done   |30
```

**t5**

```
name|date     |item       |remarks|size
abc |6-2-2015 |45mm series|done   |25
abc |5-2-2015 |45mm series|done   |30
xyz |6-2-2015 |45mm series|done   |30
```

**t6**

```
name|date     |item       |remarks|size
abc |6-2-2015 |50mm series|done   |25
abc |5-2-2015 |50mm series|done   |30
xyz |6-2-2015 |50mm series|done   |30
```

These are the tables with data and i want result like if i give name is abc i want to display all 6 table data related to that name.output result

**output**

```
name|date     |item       |remarks
abc |6-2-2015 |50mm series|done   
abc |5-2-2015 |50mm series|done   
abc |6-2-2015 |50mm series|done   
abc |5-2-2015 |50mm series|done   
abc |6-2-2015 |45mm series|done   
abc |5-2-2015 |45mm series|done   
abc |10-2-2015|40mm series|done   
abc |15-2-2015|40mm series|done   
abc |11-2-2015|35mm series|done  
abc |14-2-2015|30mm series|done   
abc |18-2-2015|25mm series|done
```

i have tried this query but getting null

```
select t1.Name,t1.Date,t1.Item,t1.Remarks
from t1 p1
inner join t2 on t1.Name=t2.Name
inner join t3 on t1.Name=t3.Name
inner join t4 on t1.Name=p4.Name
inner join t4 on t1.Name=p5.Name
inner join t5 on t1.Name=p6.Name
inner join t6  on t1.Name=p2.Name
where t1.CheckListName='abc'
```

Comment: k but it will take duplicate rows also..

Comment: `UNION` automatically filters out duplicate rows.

Comment: What you want is not a JOIN but a UNION

Comment: can you show me and in some tables have extra columns so how to do pls tell me

Comment: then, just dump all data from 6 tables into one table with all needed columns and then query it. This serves better than joins @veereshYeragatti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT * FROM t1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM t2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM t3
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM t4
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM t5
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM t6
               ) AS Total
WHERE NAME = 'abc'
```

I think you should not get any error.

Comment: if 6 tables have different columns then

Comment: then, just dump all data from 6 tables into one table with all needed columns and then query it. This serves better than joins

Comment: Above select query won't work, As 'select *' will not apply if all table table has un matched column count.

Comment: ya I know, it is assumed that it has same column count but its not

Answer (score 0):

A **Union** will select the needy rows from all table having same rows as return. Try,

```
select Name, Date, Item, Remarks
from t1 where name = 'abc'

UNION 

select Name, Date, Item, Remarks
from t2 where name = 'abc'

UNION 

select Name, Date, Item, Remarks
from t3 where name = 'abc'

UNION 

select Name, Date, Item, Remarks
from t4 where name = 'abc'

UNION 

select Name, Date, Item, Remarks
from t5 where name = 'abc'    
UNION 

select Name, Date, Item, Remarks
from t6 where name = 'abc'
```

Comment: if two tables have 6 columns then

Comment: No problem, If your result has same columns.

Comment: in my 6 table have different columns means t1 4 coloumns and t2 6 columns and t3 7 columns like that

Comment: @veeresh Yeragatti : Union is applied only to the columns mentioned in the select query.

Comment: @veeresh-yeragatti, Union works for the rows that are specified in the select query only. If you need exact result for your table post the question with the exact table schema.